# Python - Does sqlite create an integer ID column by default?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

If not, how can I do this? I cannot find out if it is there or not, and also everything I have tried so far in implementing an auto increment row ID has not worked.

Could someone point me in the direction of a good resource on this, or give me a quick hint? I've had no luck, any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In the [FAQ](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) they give an example of how to do this

Answer (score 1):

SQLite tables have a autoincrementing `ROWID` unless you specify otherwise at table creation.

From [SQLite Documentation](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

> In SQLite, table rows normally have a 64-bit signed integer ROWID which is unique among all rows in the same table. (WITHOUT ROWID tables are the exception.)
>
> You can access the ROWID of an SQLite table using one of the special column names ROWID, *ROWID*, or OID. Except if you declare an ordinary table column to use one of those special names, then the use of that name will refer to the declared column not to the internal ROWID.
>
> If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID using any of four different names, the original three names described above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any context.